# Find the row sum of a matrix using CSR or COO storing format

Tags: c++, matlab, cuda, openmp, thrust

I have for example the following matrix B which is stored in COO and CSR format (retrieved from the non-symetric example [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-9FCEB1C4-670D-4738-81D2-F378013412B0.htm#GUID-9FCEB1C4-670D-4738-81D2-F378013412B0)). Could you please suggest an efficient c++ way to apply the matlab `sum(B,2)` function using the `coo` or `csr`(or both) storing format? Because it is quit possible to work with large arrays can we do that using parallel programming (omp or CUDA (e.g, thrust))?

Any **algorithmic** or **library** based suggestions are highly appreciated.
**Thank you!**

PS: Code to construct a sparse matrix and get the `CSR` coordinates can be found for example in the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619713/matrix-multiplication-with-mkl) post.

[image]

**COO format:**                              **CSR format:**

```
       row_index col_index value                 columns  row_index  value
          1         1         1                     0         0       1
          1         2        -1                     1         3      -1
          1         3        -3                     3         5      -3   
          2         1        -2                     0         8      -2
          2         2         5                     1         11      5
          3         3         4                     2         13      4
          3         4         6                     3                 6
          3         5         4                     4                 4
          4         1        -4                     0                -4
          4         3         2                     2                 2
          4         4         7                     3                 7     
          5         2         8                     1                 8
          5         5        -5                     4                -5
```

Comment: You should take a look at the [Cusp library](https://github.com/cusplibrary/cusplibrary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For COO its pretty simple:

```
struct MatrixEntry {
    size_t row;
    size_t col;
    int value;
};

std::vector<MatrixEntry> matrix = {
    { 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 2, -1 },
    { 1, 3, -3 },
    { 2, 1, -2 },
    { 2, 2, 5 },
    { 3, 3, 4 },
    { 3, 4, 6 },
    { 3, 5, 4 },
    { 4, 1, -4 },
    { 4, 3, 2 },
    { 4, 4, 7 },
    { 5, 2, 8 },
    { 5, 5, -5 },
};

std::vector<int> sum(5);

for (const auto& e : matrix) {
    sum[e.row-1] += e.value;
}
```

and for large matrixes you can just split up the for loop into multiple smaller ranges and add the results at the end.

If you only need the sum of each row (and not columwise) CSR is also straight forward (and even more efficient):

```
std::vector<int> row_idx = { 0, 3, 5, 8, 11, 13 };
std::vector<int> value = { 1, -1, -3, -2, 5, 4, 6, 4, -4, 2, 7, 8, -5 };

std::vector<int> sum(5);

for(size_t i = 0; i < row_idx.size()-1; ++i) {
    sum[i] = std::accumulate(value.begin() + row_idx[i], value.begin() + row_idx[i + 1], 0);
}
```

Again, for parallelism you can simply split up the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience in using OpenMP so this is just a guess: In the CSR case this should be possible without any modifications. In the COO case, this would probably lead to race conditions when a value in the sum vector is modified. The most effiecent way to solve this would probably be to split up the loop manually, run the parts in parallel and then add the results in the end.

Comment: Sorry, I delete my comment accidentally, the following comments goes above MikeMB last comment: Can we add #pragma omp parallel for before for(size_t i = 0; i < row_idx.size()-1; ++i) or for (const auto& e : matrix)?

Comment: Or you can manually create the `row_idx` array from the CSR representation and use the algorithm shown there.

Comment: Your answers is very interesting especially for the `CSR` case. Because I have never use `std::accumulate`before give me some time to study and come back with possible questions if there are any. Generally, it would be interesting to see what happens if we make the code parallel applying already implemented parallel functions like the ones provided by thrust library. However, I am not sure yet if there is a libray that has in gpu implemented functions like the `std::accumulate.` In any case thanks!

Comment: @ Thoth Actually, I don't think you need to parallelize the accumulate function (although it should not be too difficult). By parallelizing the outer loop you already create more than enough possible threads to fully utilize your GPU (at least for any matrix large enough such that using a GPU makes any sense in the first place). But again, I'm also not familiar with GPU programming, so I might be mistaken.